# Capture values based on delimiter in a file

Tags: awk, sed, csv

I have a file with the below data.

File.txt:

```
[{name:dany,class:4,Subjects:5,maths:yes,science:yes,EVS:no},{name:Ane,class:5,Subjects:6,maths:yes,science:yes,EVS:Yes},{name:mike,class:5,Subjects:1,maths:yes,science:no,EVS:no}]
```

I want the output file as:

Output.txt:

```
Dany,5,Yes
Ane,6,Yes
Mike,1,No
```

I have worked as below:

`` B=`cat file.txt | awk -F '},' '{print $1}'` ``

`echo $B | awk -F , '{print $1 " " $3" " $6'}`

it displays output as 
`name:dany subjects:5 evs:no`

I have coded to take 1st line, I want the same to happen for the entire file and I need the output as I mentioned in the question

Note: Ignore the case of the words.
I have updated the input. Pls take , as separator for the fields and }, as separator for records

Comment: If your input contains valid JSON data (i.e. quoted string), you should use a JSON parser.

Comment: I am not aware of json parser.. is it possible to achieve same in shell script?

Comment: Yes, but first fix your input file such that it contains valid JSON data

Comment: i am getting this input file as a output of a curl command. So i cannot fix the input

Comment: then fix the web service providing malformed json data ;-)

Comment: :D.. Cant this be solved by awk

Comment: The input data is not consistent. There's a comma between the class and subjects fields in the first record, but not in the others.

Comment: I have updated the input. Pls take , as separator for the fields and }, as separator for records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set RS, FS, ORS and OFS to confirm to your input and output data. Assuming that your input data is consistent, you could use something like this.

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="},{";FS="[:,]";ORS="\n";OFS=",";} 1 {print $2,$4,$10}' data.txt
```

But the field separators in your input varies a lot. There's sometimes a comma, sometimes not, sometimes a space after the comma and sometimes space in front of the comma. So it seems your data source is broken.

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU awk for multi-char RS support.

Comment: I am sorry, i have edited the input to have , as a seperator

Comment: @Vandhana Then this script should work for you, assuming you are using gnu awk (mawk should also work). I think most linux distros use either gawk or mawk as the default awk flavour.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/name:/\n&/2;s/[^\n]*name:(\w*)[^\n]*subjects:(\w*)[^\n]*evs:(\w*)[^\n]*/\1,\2,\3/I;P;D' file
```

Split the lines into records, then pattern match on field names and print required fields.

Comment: I am getting printed the entire input file. Can u pls check if there is any typo in the above command.

Comment: And also pls ignore the case. Case is not important. Its my bad that i wrote the output that way.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -v RS='}' -F'[]{: ,]+' -v OFS=',' '$3!=""{print $3, $5, $11}' file
dany,4,yes
Ane,5,yes
mike,5,no
```

Answer (score 0):

The content coming back from the service is JSON-like.

You can make it JSON with a couple of sed steps. Once you do, you can use a command-line JSON parser like [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to parse it.

The labels (text before the colons) need to be quoted:

```
sed -E 's/(\s*[a-zA-Z]+)\s*:/"\1":/g'
```

The non-numeric values (text after the colons) need to be quoted as well:

```
sed -E 's/:\s*([a-zA-Z]+)\s*/:"\1"/g'
```

Putting that together with your input data, you get this pipeline:

```
echo '[{name:dany,class:4,Subjects:5,maths:yes,science:yes,EVS:no},{name:Ane,class:5,Subjects:6,maths:yes,science:yes,EVS:Yes},{name:mike,class:5,Subjects:1,maths:yes,science:no,EVS:no}]' |
    sed -E 's/(\s*[a-zA-Z]+)\s*:/"\1":/g' |
    sed -E 's/:\s*([a-zA-Z]+)\s*/:"\1"/g'
```

With that done you can get JSON that a tool like jq can parse:

```
[{"name":"dany","class":4,"Subjects":5,"maths":"yes","science":"yes","EVS":"no"},{"name":"Ane","class":5,"Subjects":6,"maths":"yes","science":"yes","EVS":"Yes"},{"name":"mike","class":5,"Subjects":1,"maths":"yes","science":"no","EVS":"no"}]
```

jq can produce a comma-separated report from that using this:

```
jq '.[] | "\(.name),\(.Subjects),\(.evs)"' --raw-output
```

- `.[]` goes through the array, object by object (`[...]` is a JSON array, `{...}` is a JSON object)
- `"\(.name)"` pulls the field "name" from the current object and outputs it
- `|` combines multiple stages of jq commands (example: `.[] | .name` outputs the name field of each object)
- `| "\(.name),\(.Subjects),\(.evs)` outputs a string with the name, Subjects, and evs fields separated by commas.

That will produce this output:

```
dany,5,null
Ane,6,null
mike,1,null
```

An entire pipeline that puts this together:

```
echo '[{name:dany,class:4,Subjects:5,maths:yes,science:yes,EVS:no},{name:Ane,class:5,Subjects:6,maths:yes,science:yes,EVS:Yes},{name:mike,class:5,Subjects:1,maths:yes,science:no,EVS:no}]' |
    sed -E 's/([a-zA-Z]+):/"\1":/g' |
    sed -E 's/:([a-zA-Z]+)/:"\1"/g' |
    jq '.[] | "\(.name),\(.Subjects),\(.evs)"' --raw-output
```